# Change specific table background

Tags: html, css

In the CSS, I have

```
table {
    max-width:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0
}
```

In HTML, I have

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
           <td>
               <img width="90px" src="logo.png">
           </td>

           <td>
               <div class="page-header">Header
           <td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

How do I change the background color of the second `<td>` without changing the other **table**'s `<td>` in CSS file?

Mind you, I'm using Bootstrap as my base CSS. And it's kinda complicated when it comes to modifying the code.

Comment: set id for it and change waht you want. Or set td.firsttd {background:red;} in css

Comment: Give a class to second `td` and set background to that class

Comment: @OneTrickPony He/She meant the 1st `<td>`

Comment: How do you differentiate between tables?

Answer (score 4):

Using CSS you can something like

```
    table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2){
         background:red;
    }
```

Comment: psuedo class selectors are probably the best, most efficient way here. more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Note that this is not cross-browser compatible and also not really needed in this case.. Might cause more problems later on.

Comment: This is part of CSS3 - here is table of supported browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: Yhep - since about 16% of users won't see it, I'd say, use another solution.. Maybe unless it's not really important. And if the nth-child selector is really required, just to be sure, it's better to use it with jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Add a class to your desired `<td>` element.

In that `class`, specify for desired `background`

[See here for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7uFZm/)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer whichever helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to the td you want to change (for example, use 'headerTd'):

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
    <td><img width="90px" src="logo.png"></td>

    <td class="headerTd"><div class="page-header">Header<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then add the following rule to your css:

```
.headerTd{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for styling only the 2nd  simply give the style attribute.

```
style="color:red"
```

Comment: Style within html is not a good practice. Use css stylesheet.

Comment: @RoyK excuse my curiousity, but WHY? =)

Comment: ya you are correct Roy . It's because of some maintenance or we can say reusable issues. I agree ur point.

Answer (score 0):

```
.secondTD {
    background:red;
}


<table class="table">
        <tr>
        <td><img width="90px" src="logo.png"></td>

        <td class="secondTD"><div class="page-header">Header<td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

But if you want without classes, then

```
table:tr:td {
    background:red;
}


<table class="table">
        <tr>
        <td><img width="90px" src="logo.png"></td>

        <td><div class="page-header">Header<td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

in case when every row with first td:

```
table>tr:td {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: But he said second <td>.. This is a bit confusing